# Deleted System Partition of windows 7: How to set up again

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

Last night, I tried installing Backtrack 5 RC3 on my PC that had Win 7 installed which was quite stable, so I would never want to loose it. But I did it :(

I've got 2 Hard Disks, one (Let me call it disk WD), and the other (which I'll call SD), having no use as it has been dynamically parted, so no os'es can be installed on it. 
So, the WD has 2 partition, the main part (C: 40 gb) was free of any os's and the left (D: 40 gb) was on which Win 7 was installed. I tried to shrink C: to make space for Backtrack, but as it was system partition, disk manager did not completed it. I knew that if I'll format the C: part with Backtrack, my Win 7 was going to die, as it was the system partition. I even tried to shift the boot files to D:, but as I installed Backtrack, by wiping out the C: partition, I was no longer able to boot to Win 7. I tried to repair the installation by using the Win 7 live USB key, but it did not worked. Then I tried to wipe out the Backtrack partition and its swap to again make space for another Win 7 installation on C: so as to save the other installation, but even after deleting the BT partition and creating new NTFS partition on it, I was unable to set it up.

I saw in my Laptop there is a 100 mb of system partition used for Win 7, so I guess this was a good solution so as to have dual boot on your pc, but I am unable to setup that system partition again. And I can't afford to loose my old Win 7, as it has got 100's of important productivity app installed which'll take more than a month time to set up and be back on track.

Any suggestion as on how can I create a system partition within the setup, and it it was a 100 mb partition, then it would be the best.

Comment: You said your Windows 7 is installed in `D:`, but then you said `C:` is system partition. Which one is correct?

Comment: See, I have 2 partitions, C: and D:. OS is installed on D: but C: was being used as the reserved system partition, like the one of 100mb invisible partition reserved for os, that comes with PC's having stock Win 7 installed (to store boot info etc.) My C: drive was being used as that but it was visible to me and I used it for storing other data.

Comment: Inglis: The MS terminology is that the "system partition" is the first one, the one that's normally hidden, and the "boot partition" is where the OS lives. Check out the annotations in Disk Manager and you'll see. Cyberpks was using the correct terminology.